# Is there way to convert a PSD or Illustrator file to PowerPoint?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, microsoft-powerpoint

I got a bunch of PSD and Illustrator files and my boss wants that ability to edit the information in the files without having to ask me to do it.  This would be more like editing just the text, there would be no need to edit the graphical elements. Is that a way to convert these file to PowerPoint?

Comment: Sounds like the question is about essentially the same problem as http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/best-way-to-send-layouts-with-editable-text-to-writers-editors-who-dont-have-de but with a reference to Powerpoint (why Powerpoint?) thrown in.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  As for the question why PowerPoint, it's because that is what she is comfortable in and she can export it to PDF.  If all she is editing is text ... why not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a direct way that I'm aware of.  What you could do is export the background elements as a PNG and use it as a background in Powerpoint.  If you set the master slides to use the exported background and do all your text styling there, you could have a reasonable platform for your boss to do simple edits while retaining control over the presentation style.

Keep in mind that your graphics will lose some of their quality when printed.  I believe (though am not sure and can't check right now) that PowerPoint will resize whatever images you give it.  Even if you supply a graphic that should print at 300 PPI for a letter-size page, PP may resize it to where it's essentially 72ppi and a crappy print.  I'm not absolutely certain of this, but you probably want to sample some prints from PowerPoint before doing any major work creating templates.

Comment: I did a quick check and PowerPoint does indeed resize graphics to fit its purpose and this does result in lower-quality printing than you might expect.  It may be possible to overcome this by fiddling with settings, but at least with the default settings it may be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

PowerPoint and probably many other slideshow programs (e.g. Impress) can import PDF content.

Current versions of Illustrator save .ai files in a format very similar to PDFs, and you can also save with PDF compatibility so that the AI file itself will open in PDF readers. Photoshop can also save as Photoshop PDF. And both programs also allow you to export as PDF.

However, I'm not sure why you want to use PowerPoint to allow your boss to edit the text in the files, unless they're supposed to be slideshows in the first place.

Comment: I saved as Photoshop PDF and tried opening with Powerpoint. No luck. I don't see an import with PowerPoint and couldn't open the PDF.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith: It looks like you need to open the PDF file in Adobe Reader and then copy the content from within Adobe Reader and paste it into PowerPoint: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Using-PowerPoint-2010-and-2007-with-PDF-files-fcd0781a-7620-428a-90ac-17ddcc7297c9

Answer (score 1):

Try this software:

http://www.pptxtreme.com/psdimport.asp

I have used this company's software before and it works as stated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Illustrator CS5 and Powerpoint 2003. I exported to Windows Metafile, and then I use  insert picture from file in Powerpoint. If you right-click on the image and select edit picture, you can then edit it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Export files as PDF, then open in Acrobat pro and export the PDF to powerpoint.  The fonts do lose their formatting.