# InDesign: Any way to prevent styles from being edited?

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, paragraph-styles, character-styles

I want my document's styles not be editable (paragraph, character and object styles).

Can I lock these somehow, or link the styles to another document which is out of reach of employee?

Comment: If you give the users access to the .indd file, they will have access to everything. Perhaps using InCopy or creating templates with only sections being editable would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be useful, but *no* unfortunatelly InDesign does not have such features. That is basicly why they are also selling [InCopy](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/best-way-to-send-layouts-with-editable-text-to-writers-editors-who-dont-have-de/7090#7090) as a separate product, which allows editors to work on InDesign files without touching the styles and page layout of a document.